# Determine all probability distributions

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

> > Let $(\mathbb{N}_0,\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}_0),\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $A_k:=\left\{k,k+1,k+2,\ldots\right\}$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}_0$. Assume that
> >     $$
> > \mathbb{P}(A_{k+l}|A_k)=\mathbb{P}(A_l)~~~\text{for all}~~~k,l\in\mathbb{N}_0.
> > $$
> >     Determine all probability distributions $\mathbb{P}$ on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}_0)$ with this property.

I did not find a real understanding to this task. Can you give me some help how to start this task?

Of course I made some efforts, which lead me to:
$$
\mathbb{P}(A_{k+l}|A_k)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(A_{k+l}\cap A_k)}{\mathbb{P}(A_k)}=\mathbb{P}(A_l)~~~\Leftrightarrow~~~\mathbb{P}(A_{k+l}\cap A_k)=\mathbb{P}(A_k)\mathbb{P}(A_l).~~~~~(*)
$$

For $l=0$ it is $\mathbb{P}(A_{k+l}\cap A_k)=\mathbb{P}(A_k)$, so that $(*)$ says that $\mathbb{P}(A_l)=1$.

For $l>0$ it is $\mathbb{P}(A_{k+l}\cap A_k)=\mathbb{P}(A_{k+l})$, so that $(*)$ says that $\mathbb{P}(A_{k+l})=\mathbb{P}(A_k)\mathbb{P}(A_l)$.

Furthermore, the usual properties of a probability measure have to be fullfilled, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(\emptyset)=0$, $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{N}_0)=1$, $\mathbb{P}\left(\biguplus_n B_n\right)=\sum_n \mathbb{P}(B_n)$ for disjoint $B_n\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}_0)$.

But to be honest, I do not know how to use this... or if this is the right beginning...

Comment: you have a homomorphism from $(\mathbb{N}_0,+)\to(\mathbb{R},\cdot)$, $k\mapsto\mathbb{P}(A_k)$, so your class of probability measures includes $\mathbb{P}(\{k\})=a^{k-1}$ for $0<a<1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=P(A_1)$, then $a$ is in $[0,1]$ and $P(A_{k+1}\mid A_k)=a$ for every $k$, which, since $A_{k+1}\subset A_k$, implies $P(A_{k+1})=aP(A_k)$ for every $k$. An easy induction shows that $P(A_k)=a^k$ for every $k\geqslant0$, hence $P(\{k\})=(1-a)a^k$ for every $k\geqslant0$ since $\{k\}=A_k\setminus A_{k+1}$. The sequence $(A_k)$ is nonincreasing with intersection $\varnothing$ hence $P(A_k)\to P(\varnothing)=0$ when $k\to\infty$, that is, $a$ is in $[0,1)$. Finally:

> If $P(A_1)=0$, $P(\{0\})=1$ hence $P$ is the Dirac measure at $0$. If $P(A_1)$ is in $(0,1)$, $P$ is the geometric distribution with parameter $a$. And $P(A_1)=1$ is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Let write $A_k$ as $(X\geq k)$, since that's a more normal way of writing it.  Then the statement we're given is

$$P(X \geq k + \ell \; |\; X \geq k) = P(X \geq \ell).$$

We can rewrite this as

$$P(X \geq k + \ell) = P(x \geq \ell)\,P(X \geq k)$$

Write $p_i$ for $P(X = i)$.  Then

$$P(X \geq k) = 1 - p_0 - p_1 - \cdots - p_{k-1}$$

so the previous expression becomes

$$(1 - p_0  - \cdots - p_{k+\ell-1}) = (1 - p_0  - \cdots - p_{k-1})(1 - p_0  - \cdots - p_{\ell-1})$$

Take $\ell = 1$:

$$(1 - p_0  - \cdots - p_{k}) = (1 - p_0  - \cdots - p_{k-1})(1 - p_0)$$

You should be able to see what to do from there.

Comment: Not so clear to me, sorry. I got $p_k=p_0(1-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}p_i)$.

Comment: So, given $p_0$, that uniquely determines every other value of $p_i$, right?

Comment: Yes, if $p_0$ is given, then I know $p_1$, when I know $p_1$, I know $p_2$ and so on. And what do I have to do now?

Comment: Well, which values of $p_0$ give you a valid probability distribution that satisfies all the criteria?

Comment: I really do not know, but I tried... for example $P(\mathbb{N}_0)=P(X\geq 0)$ has to be 1. But I do not see how to choose $p_0$ to do so.

Comment: Well, what are $p_1$ and $p_2$ in terms of $p_0$?

Comment: I do not see the trick yet. Anyway $p_1=p_0(1-p_0)$ and $p_2=p_0-2p_0^2+p_0^3$.

Comment: By the way: You strategy is to work with $\mathbb{P}\circ X^{-1}$ in order to determine $\mathbb{P}$, where $X\colon \mathbb{N}_0\to\mathbb{N}_0$? Why does this strategy (that I did not finish yet...) work to determine ALL probability distributions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by $X : \mathbb{N}_0 \to \mathbb{N}_0$.  $X$ is just a random variable with this distribution.

Comment: $X\colon \mathbb{N}_0\to\mathbb{N}_0$ is a random variable: I mean you wrote $A_k$ as $(X\geq k)=\left\{\omega: X(\omega)\geq k\right\}$. This is you are determinung $\mu:=\mathbb{P}\circ X^{-1}$ as a probability measure on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}_0)$ that fullfills the conditions?  - Please help me to finish your idea, I do not come along.

Comment: Okay, sure, if you want to be technical, a natural number-valued random variable is a function $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{N}_0$, and in this case $\Omega = \mathbb{N}_0$ and $X$ is just the identity function on $\mathbb{N}_0$.  But that's over-formalizing things.  You have a probability measure on a countable space, so we don't have to think about events; it's determined by the probability of each outcome individually.

Comment: "Its determined by the probability of each outcome individually" - Could you explian that please?

Comment: Measures are countably additive by definition.

Comment: Could you pls do me a favour and end your proof? Maybe I then see what you mean the whole time.